# How to estimate server size requirements for SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server

I have spoken to a couple of server providers now trying to estimate the cost feasibility for a web development project but not really getting a clear answer.

The main burden of the project is the database which will hold 20 million rows of data with 5 columns per row (10 letter code, 10 letter code, 10 letter code, 10 digit integer, URL (say 20 characters long on average).

The main question is how to estimate the GB of storage necessary for something like that? (with SQL Server ). [I don't have a copy of SQL Server to test].

The second question really is about speed and I/O requirements, but that is probably a question way down the line after a demo is developed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your 10 letter codes and 20 letter url are stored as nchar and your 10 digit integer is stored as an int, it looks like per [this](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/sql-server-data-type-reference) table you're looking at 124 bytes per row: 20 per nchar(10), 4 per int, 40 per nchar(20).  That means that at 20 million rows you're just over 2.3 GB.

Comment: I'll qualify this by admitting that I'm not a SQL expert (I just searched for the table on data types, looked up the difference between text types like nchar/nvarchar, and then did some math) so it's possible that I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks for that, do you know about user loads and ways to estimate server performance requirements based on number of database queries per user? (in terms of RAM/sockets etc..?)

Comment: Nope, not sure short of doing some prototyping.

Answer (score 5):

There is an entire MSDN chapter on the subject: [Estimating the Size of a Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187445). It is important to know how many non-clustered indexes you need (are you going to seek data one any of those 'code' column?) and what is the clustered index key. Each subject has, again, a topic on MSDN:

- [Estimate the Size of a Clustered Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178085)
- [Estimate the Size of a Nonclustered Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190620)

Additionally you can deploy [Row Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280576) or [Page Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280464) to reduce the size of your table(s). And if you opt for Unicode columsn you can also enable [Unicode Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240835).

Your performance requirements will be driven mostly by your load (ie. your queries). You did not specify anything about how are you going to query the the database (ranges? aggregates, singleton lookups?, BI?) and how is the database updated (read-only?, ETL?, OLTP?). There are tipc on how to [Monitor and Tune for Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189081) but more important is to design your application for performance. There are many details, eg. read [How Data Access Code Affects Database Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx) but, by a large margin, the most important task is to tune your data model (the layout of tables and indexes) to your access pattern (how are you going to query the database).

Comment: Hi Remus, thank you for that very helpful answer, I will read diligently.  I haven't learned enough about databases yet it seems!  My second worry as you mentioned is the load from queries, there could be thousands of queries happening from users at the same time.  I am going to use this grid: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/filteringtemplatecolumns/defaultcs.aspx and it is my understanding that the filtering uses a paging method for queries.

Comment: The benchmarks for 300,000 rows per this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/performance/linq/defaultcs.aspx is a little over a second to search for data in one column. Do you know whether you can estimate how large the response times could get under certain simultaneous searches based on these stats alone if you know the specs of the server?